# How to avoid circular references among modules that share relational data

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

On non-Orchard applications the pattern is to isolate data models (and data access code) in a project which is referenced by things like a domain / business logic libraries, web application projects, web service projects, etc.

The idea with Orchard *appears to be* restricting a data model to exactly one module with no intention of having any relation to other modules' data model.

"Restrict" is perhaps a bit harsh or inexact--maybe "limit" is a better choice of wording here. Given two modules, A and B, and while working on module A we can add a reference to module B, and use repositories for entities from it. But when working on module B, and the need arises to access data from module A, we cannot--at least not elegantly within the framework. The circular reference problem exists here.

In this circumstance I'm inclined to several approaches:

1. consolidate the two modules into a single one (and have to deal with a potentially burdensome and risky data migration)
2. resort to accessing the data directly without using the framework or a repository
3. put all data models in a single module that is referenced by all other custom modules (again, more data migration risk)
4. raise a hand here...

Is any of this a correct interpretation of the Orchard software designers' intention for modules and data relations?

Comment: If 2 modules are dependent of each other, they should be one. Or you should put all common data in a separate module, that both other reference. In any other case, your data model might be incorrect if you are in need of a circular reference

Answer (score 1):

From an architectural point of view, if you need a circular dependency between two modules, then that usually means that it should be a single module.

One thing I do quite often in similar scenarios is to share abstract definitions and interfaces instead of sharing the implementation. You can create a module (or just a regular assembly) which contains only interfaces defining you data model. Then you can share this library between the module which implements the model and the modules which depend on the model. The only restriction is that you have to access the model through the interfaces, not the concrete implementation.

For example, check out how `ITitleAspect` is implemented in Orchard core. You can implement similar interfaces for your model and share them in a separate assembly. This works very nicely with content parts and content items.

Comment: This is similar to what I had in mind for points 1 and 3 above. In general this is the preferred way of making things loosely coupled--coding to interfaces instead of concrete implementations. It is a good bonus with your answer to have an example here to follow with the Orchard core.